# Execute Perl script from Java tomcat returns ever 255 exit code

Tags: java, perl, ssh

I have a problem, I'm trying to execute a PERL script allocated on another server. If I execute the command in Linux Shell, the script run correctly. If I execute the script allocating the perl script in the same server of apache Tomcat, runs ok, but when I try to execute the script through ssh by Tomcat, always end with error code 255.

Perl Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my $sleeptime = 10;
sleep($sleeptime);

my $argumento=$ARGV[0];
if ( $argumento eq "A" ) {
    exit 0;
} else {
    exit 192;
}
```

Now, this is the code in Java file

```
String command = "ssh root@myserver.com '/usr/bin/perl /var/www/testPerl.pl A'";
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
process.waitFor();  
if ( process.exitValue() == 0 ) {
    System.out.println("Show icon ok");
} else {
    System.out.println("Show error");
}
```

If I change command variable to

```
String command = "/usr/bin/perl /var/www/testPerl.pl A";
```

The return code is ok ( 0 or 192 )

Is mandatory to execute remotely, so I can't copy the real PERL to tomcat directory. I did localy just for test.

Comment: Does the ssh command run when you enter it directly (without Tomcat)? Do you get any error messages? Is passwordless SSH set up for the Tomcat user? Does the script in `/var/www` also exist on the server you ssh into?

Comment: When I run using shell Linux, it runs perfect. Returns 0 if I run with "A" argument, or 192 when I run with other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the SSH call from the Tomcat server as the tomcat user, e.g.

```
ssh root@myserver.com '/usr/bin/perl /var/www/testPerl.pl A'
```

Try adding *-v* as ssh argument and capture the output to see if the ssh connection is working. Maybe you're missing RSAAuthentication (key-based instead of password-based) or something else doesn't work as it should.

Try returning some value from Perl for debugging:

```
print "I'm running (STDOUT)\n";
print STDERR "I'm running (STDERR)\n";
```

Comment: ... I'm just a ( http://i2.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/010/277/069.jpg ). I just created a rsa for developer user, but no for tomcat user (who execute the .class files...)

Now, after creating RSA for tomcat user, works like a charm